# Passing data from textfield to next view

Tags: xcode, swift, view, xcode6, segue

I am trying to develop a basic app in Xcode 6.1 and Swift language.

I cant seem to find any IOS 8, Xcode6 and Swift resources yet that help with this. Everything is still xcode 5 and IOS 7.

I have the whole story board done with images buttons and segues. just need to script it.

There are 6 segues all with segue "show".

I am just trying to capture one text field per view controller. upon button press for the segue to the next view controller.

the prepareForSegue thing confuses me.

how do I capture the data from a text field save it to a variable on button press and send that variable info to the next view controller?

That text field I want saved to a variable or let that I can have the final view controller access all the data input from each view controller and then do some basic math.

Any body can help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have two view Controllers here is how you will pass value to the second view controller.

```
 class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {
      @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField = nil

      ...

      override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
             if (segue.identifier == "segueTest") {
                 var svc = segue!.destinationViewController as ViewControllerB;
                 svc.passedValue = textField.text
             }
      }
 }

 class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {
     var passedValue: String?
     ... 
     override func viewDidLoad() {
          ...
          if let myPassedData = passedValue {
               println(myPassedData)
          }
```

or use

```
             let myPassedData = passedValue ?? "" 
               println(myPassedData)
          }
     }
 }
```

Comment: awesome I will try that out now!

Comment: I got an error. Consecutive declaration on a line must be seperated by ";" on line     override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {

Comment: I did also notice I was adding the two overrides to teh same view Controller but I remedied that and still was getting teh same error on both view controllers

Comment: Go ahead and generate a master detail app in your Xcode and look at the method signature for `prepareForSegue` you can adapt the snippet I gave you to the generated code.

Comment: This is what mine spits out:     // MARK: - Segues

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as NSManagedObject
            (segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController).detailItem = object
            }
        }
    }

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks!